# how to access eloquent eager loading collection in blade template?

Tags: eloquent, laravel-blade, eager-loading, laravel-5

I fetch posts from a database with answers to them and the post author (user).
The result looks good in `dd($posts)`. I can see all needed information.

the model and relationships:

```
class Post extends Model {

    public function postanswers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Myapp\Postanswer','post');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Myapp\User','user','id');
    }
}
```

the query:

```
$posts = Post::with('user','postanswers')->paginate(20);
```

How can I loop through the results in a blade template, access the user's username and count the post answers? Here is one thing I tried, but nothing seems to work:

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
    {{ $post->user->username }}
@endforeach
```

I can't find out what I am doing wrong.

**edit:**
I found that `{{ $post->User->username }}` works. uppercase U

Comment: I'm surprised the uppercase U makes a difference. Actually `{{ $post->user->username }}` is correct according to the relationships you posted.

Comment: You should consider posting your last line as an answer, rather than part of your question.  It's okay to post an answer to your own question, and it will make it more apparent that there is a solution to the problem you had.

Comment: I am ok in that way. no upper case